# electron-forge start failed due to failure on installing electron-prebuilt-compile

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I want to start creating app using electron-forge but it cannot Install NPM Dependencies.

Here is the error I am getting after this command: `electron-forge init my-new-project --template=react`

`

```
An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\p2761065\Projects\Charter_Gateway4\my-new-project\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\package.json'
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\p2761065\Projects\Charter_Gateway4\my-new-project\node_modules\electron-prebuilt-compile\package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\dist\init\init-npm.js:127:32
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.tryCatcher (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at PromiseSpawn._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\generators.js:97:49)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:574:26)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\Users\p2761065\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-forge\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
```

`